# Кроссбраузерность firefox

Tags: css, кроссбраузерность

https://layout.alicom.dp.ua/jp-desk/
Имею такой баг в firefox 49. Подскажите пожалуйста решение. flex он уже поддерживает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какое имя у бага? Неправильная "обводка"? И... у них одинаковый CSS? Или это баг SVG?

Comment: Могу только предположить что это у вас проблема не в флексах, а в псевдоэлементе который спозиционирован абсолютом, но ни `top`, ни `left` и тд не задано, встречал подобные съезжания на iphone

Comment: @Алексей ну тут срабатывает flex в этом случае же и нет смысла в top и left.

Comment: @AndryLomakin встречал подобную ошибку решил как описал выше, т.к. уже ни времени ни сил не было биться с ней тогда. А так да вы правы насчет флексов, должны срабатывать, но не срабатывают)

Comment: Поместите код с примером проблемы прямо в текст вопроса без сторонних ссылок, иначе вопрос окажется бесполезен для базы знаний и будет закрыт

Answer (score 1):

У вас не отработал display:flex, поэтому псевдоэлементы `:after` съехали. Попробуйте добавить затычку - вендорное свойство `display:-moz-flexbox`.

Но вообще конкретно ваша задача решается на порядок проще и без лишних элементов. Достаточно затать круглому блоку несколько теней:

```
.palitra .palitra__div__flex__items .flex__items__div__item a .img {
    border: 2px solid #ffde00;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 9px #fff, 0 0 0 10px #ffde00;
}

.palitra .palitra__div__flex__items .flex__items__div__item a:hover .img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffde00;
}
```